# Plotting based on 3 values

Tags: pine-script

I found a script and would like to adapt it to have alerts and plot on the main chart but I am stuck as to how to do it.

I am looking to plot a signal when all 3 bars in the histogram are light color and then again when they all switch to the dark signal

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

```
'''
study(title="3 Linear Regression Curve", shorttitle="Triple LRC", overlay=false)
src = close
len1 = input(10)
len2 = input(14)
len3 = input(30)
offset = 0
reg1 = linreg(src, len1, offset)
reg2 = linreg(src, len2, offset)
reg3 = linreg(src, len3, offset)

hist1 = 3
hist2 = 2
hist3 = 1

plot(hist1,style=histogram,color=reg1>reg1[1]?aqua:blue,transp=0,linewidth=3)
plot(hist2,style=histogram,color=reg2>reg2[1]?yellow:orange,transp=0,linewidth=3)
plot(hist3,style=histogram,color=reg3>reg3[1]?lime:green,transp=0,linewidth=3)
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, where you use `overlay=false`, it is nice to have another script to see your possible buy and sell signals with `plotshape()` function.

You should be careful with your buy and sell signals. You will get alerts for each bar where one of your signals is `TRUE`. Ideally, you want to have one BUY signal and then one SELL signal.

Have a look at the following script:

```
//@version=4
study(title="3 Linear Regression Curve Overlay", shorttitle="Triple LRC", overlay=true)
src = close
len1 = input(10)
len2 = input(14)
len3 = input(30)

var isLong = false      // Flag to see if you are already long
var isShort = false     // Flag to see if you are already short

offset = 0
reg1 = linreg(src, len1, offset)
reg2 = linreg(src, len2, offset)
reg3 = linreg(src, len3, offset)

hist1 = 3
hist2 = 2
hist3 = 1

buyCondition = not isLong and (reg1 > reg1[1]) and (reg2 > reg2[1]) and (reg3 > reg3[1])        // Go long only if you are not already long
sellCondition = not isShort and (reg1 <= reg1[1]) and (reg2 <= reg2[1]) and (reg3 <= reg3[1])   // Go short only if you are not already short

if (buyCondition)       // Set flags
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellCondition)      // Set flags
    isLong := false
    isShort := true
plotshape(series=buyCondition, text="BUY", style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=sellCondition, text="SELL", style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small)
```

This will plot BUY only when you are short, and SELL only when you are long.

Once you establish that, you just convert your buy and sell condition to alerts.

```
//@version=4
study(title="3 Linear Regression Curve", shorttitle="Triple LRC", overlay=false)
src = close
len1 = input(10)
len2 = input(14)
len3 = input(30)

var isLong = false
var isShort = false

offset = 0
reg1 = linreg(src, len1, offset)
reg2 = linreg(src, len2, offset)
reg3 = linreg(src, len3, offset)

hist1 = 3
hist2 = 2
hist3 = 1

buyCondition = not isLong and (reg1 > reg1[1]) and (reg2 > reg2[1]) and (reg3 > reg3[1])        // Go long only if you are not already long
sellCondition = not isShort and (reg1 <= reg1[1]) and (reg2 <= reg2[1]) and (reg3 <= reg3[1])   // Go short only if you are not already short

if (buyCondition)       // Set flags
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellCondition)      // Set flags
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

alertcondition(condition=buyCondition, title="Alert: All light colors", message="BUY")
alertcondition(condition=sellCondition, title="Alert: All dark colors", message="SELL")

plot(hist1, style=plot.style_histogram, color= reg1 > reg1[1] ? color.aqua:color.blue, transp=0,linewidth=3)
plot(hist2, style=plot.style_histogram, color= reg2 > reg2[1] ? color.yellow:color.orange, transp=0,linewidth=3)
plot(hist3, style=plot.style_histogram, color= reg3 > reg3[1] ? color.lime:color.green, transp=0,linewidth=3)
```

Please remember that you should set the alerts manually as described [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Alert_conditions.html) and [here](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#alerts).

[image]

Comment: Wow that is fantastic, that would have taken me forever to figure out, I really appreciate your help and insights.

Comment: One important detail - more related to the real use case: I suggest you also backtest it as a strategy with TradingView `strategy()` with the according entries and exits, or simulate it yourself in Excel, Matlab, or whatever. Here's why: although it looks graphically amazing, and there are certainly some nice catches, you must be careful that calculations are here most likely triggering a flag at the close of bars, not at their very beggining, and that can radically change profitability. Good luck!

Comment: Good point @GlaucoEsturilio. Therefore I'd recommend using historical values and see if your condition was true one bar ago instead.